# python-docx: how to read value in dropdown menu

Tags: python, dropdown, python-docx

I'm using the docx package to load the content of a word document into a pandas dataframe. This works perfectly fine except for one text value that's in a dropdown list. It doesn't create an error but it's simply not detected. As I understood it's probably caused by the fact that the drop down value is wrapped in some kind of 'container XML'. Only have a very basic XML knowledge so not really sure what I need to do with this info

**Update:**

This is part of the code:

```
# library import
import os
import docx
import pandas as pd  

# input folder containg the docx document
input_path='//server/docs/input/'
    
# add files to list
files_list = []
for i in os.listdir(input_path):
    if not i.startswith('~'): #avoids opening any hidden files
        files_list.append(i)

nbr_files=0

for file in files_list:
      
    # document object creation
    path = input_path + file
    document=docx.Document(path)
    
    # initialize list to store docx properties
    texts=[]
    styles=[]
    parent_styles=[]
    font_colors=[]
    para_number=[]
    para_alignment =[]
    white_line=[]
    
    # makes dedicated list with content an style of the different paragrahps 
    i=0
    for para in document.paragraphs:
        for run in para.runs:
            para_number.append(i)
            texts.append(run.text)
            styles.append(run.style.name)
            parent_styles.append(para.style.name) 
        i=i+1
    
    
    df=pd.DataFrame({'Paragraph Number':para_number,'Paragraph Styles':parent_styles,'Text Styles':styles,'Text Values':texts, 'Output':0})
```

**Update 2:**

I'm close to the solution (thanks yvesonline) as I now have the following in a *bs4.element.ResultSet*

```
[<w:sdtContent><w:p w14:paraId="743E8A10" w14:textId="67CB64E7" w:rsidP="00AC046A" w:rsidR="00F52254" w:rsidRDefault="00436522"><w:r><w:t>TESTTEST</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:sdtContent>]
```

Any idea on how I can get the info between <w:t> and </w:t>, ie TESTTEST

Comment: Can you please show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61849800/python-docx-read-dropdown-lists-in-a-specific-cell-of-a-table

Comment: Checked that post but have difficulties understanding the following line of code: xml_data = zip_file.read('word/document.xml'). Don't understand where the 'word/' is suddenly coming from. Again, I'm quite an XML noob so probably that's the reason

Comment: It just reads the `xml` content of your Word file, you can copy & paste it, the `word` is essentially the path inside the Zip file.

Comment: Ah yes I see. I was misled by the fact that filename in that example is also 'document'. Thanks!